# Dynamically changing variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown

I have unlimited countdown timer and price of some stuff. I want to price up every day depending on the timer. How can i automatically change price every day and show it to user?

Here is my code:

```
        var d = new Date();

         /*Get current date*/
        var month = d.getMonth()+1;
        var day = d.getDate();

        /*Get date for timer(current + 1 day)*/
        var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
        (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
        (day<10 ? '0' : '') + (day+1);

        /*My price*/
        var price = 1000;
        var priceup = day+1;

        $('#price').html(price);
        if(priceup <= day) {price += 500; $('#price').html(price);}

        $('#clock').countdown(output, function(event) {
            $(this).html(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
        });
```

I'm using "The final countdown" timer http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

Comment: Do you update price only in front end or want it to change in back end (php) too?

Comment: Only in front end. But in php i see only 1 solution depending on mysql time events.

Comment: No, in PHP you use Cron Job for scheduled processes

Comment: ok, but can i do this only in front-end?

Comment: Yes, but it will always be dependent on back end price.

Comment: Ok, depending on loading what harder for server cron jobs or mysql events?